# How to include a non-breaking hyphen in hyperlink text in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I want to include a URL in word document, both as text people can read, and a link they can click.  The URL has a hyphen in it.  I don't want the URL to get broken across lines.

When I use a regular hyphen, the link works, but the text displayed gets broken.

When I use a non-breaking hyphen (Ctrl+Shift+-) Word removes the hyphen from the link.

When I try and manually edit the hyperlink, I can't add a non-breaking hyphen into the Text to display field using Ctrl+Shift+-.

If I was writing this is HTML I could just do:

```
<a href="http://www.my-link.com/">www.my&#8209;link.com</a>
```

How do I get Word to do the equivalent?

Comment: Non-breaking hyphens are not supported in HTML so Word won't let you put one in the text portion of a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an older version of Word but it has the same problem. I was able to workaround the limitation by holding down the Alt key and typing `030` on the numeric keypad then releasing the Alt Key at the spot I wanted the non-breaking hyphen. Afterwards I had to manually select and make the displayed text into a hyperlink with the proper `href` value. It may also be necessary or helpful to turn off the Auto-Formatting of Hyperlinks in Auto-Correct Options.

[image: screenshot show Word not breaking a hyperlink after a hypen]

Comment: Hmm- I don't have a numeric keypad on my laptop, and when I press Alt, I get all the Alt keys displayed on the menu items. :-(

Comment: @dunxd: My laptop also lacks a numeric keypad. However there;s a virtual one composed of keys from several rows to the right of the center of the keyboard. These key all have a blue digit on them in addition to the normal letter. If I hold down the `Fn` key, those keys all become the digit shown on them. So, to simulate having a numeric keyboard, I need to first press and hold the `Fn` key, then also press the `Alt` key, before pressing the keys for `030`. An viable alternative to all this fancy keyboarding would be to use something like [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org) and make a macro.

Comment: Thanks - I don't think I ever figured out how to use that at feature on my laptop till now. And extra thanks for coming back to a question from nearly three years back! Super User just keeps on giving!

Comment: You're welcome. Surprised you recalled your nearly 3 year old question. Since writing my original answer I've upgraded to Word 2013 and can now use Ctrl+Shift+- to enter non-breaking hyphens into the text-to-display portion of the hyperlink edit dialog box (although what's in my answer still works, too).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using word 2013. Here is something that seems to work for me.

1. insert a hyperlink: something/foo-bar/otherthing
2. in the text of the document, go to the hyphen and replace it with a non-breaking hyphen (ctrl-shift-"-")
3. edit the hyperlink:

   - in the "Text to display" text box you have something like:
     something/foo bar/otherthing
   - in the "Address" text box you have something like:
     something/foo%1ebar/otherthing
4. in the "Text to display" text box, select "foo bar"
5. copy this to the clipboard (ctrl-"c")
6. in the "Address" text box, replace the "%1e" with a hyphen
   (this is also changing the "Text to display" text box ....)
7. in the "Text to display" text box, select "foo-bar" and paste what you selected in 4)-5) from the clipboard (ctrl-v)

Comment: When I try this in Word 2010, it appears to work, but when I follow the link, it has removed the hyphen completely, and when I edit it again it has replaced the Address with something/foo%1ebar/otherthing rather than something/foo-bar/otherthing